# Where to find the latest news in web application security?

Tags: web-application, disclosure

Looking around for recommendations on informative and valuable websites, blogs and/or people to follow to stay up to date on web application security, generally new vulnerabilities disclosures.

Currently I am following a broader spectra regarding computer security such as Security Now, Securelist (by Kaspersky), OWASP and ExploitDB. However, I have for some time now tried to find a good source of information specific to web application security. Any advice would be much appriciated!

Comment: Updated the question. Generally looking for information and disclosures of new vulnerabilities.